# How to fix update on unmounted component?

Tags: reactjs

Hello i have an function for a lightbox but when i opend the lightbox i get a warning that i can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function. Can anyone help me to fix this?

```
export function ImageLightBox({ image }) {
  const KEY_ESC = 27
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <div className={cx(styles.component )} aria-modal='true'>
      <Lightbox {...{ visible, image }} onClose={() => setVisible(false)} />
      <div className={styles.content}>
        <img className={styles.image} src={image.src} width={image.width} alt={image.alt} height={image.height} />
        <div className={styles.buttonOpen}><LinkSecondary onClick={OpenLightbox} iconLeft={iconZoom}>Vergroot</LinkSecondary></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )

  function OpenLightbox() {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown)
    setVisible(true)
    function handleKeyDown(e) {
      if (e.which === KEY_ESC) setVisible(false)
    }
  }
}

function Lightbox({ visible, onClose, image }) {
  const animatedBackground = useTransition(!visible, null, {
    from: { opacity: 0, position: 'absolute' },
    enter: { opacity: 1, position: 'absolute' },
    leave: { opacity: 0, position: 'absolute' },
    config: config.gentle,
  })
  const portalNode = usePortalNode(visible ? '_rootImageWithLightbox' : '_rootImageWithLightbox-default')
  return portalNode && ReactDOM.createPortal(
    animatedBackground.map(({ props, key }) => (
      visible && <animated.div style={props} key={key} className={styles.componentLightbox}>
        <div className={styles.buttonClose}><LinkPrimary hideText onClick={onClose} iconRight={closeSvg}>Sluiten</LinkPrimary></div>
        <img className={styles.imageLightbox} srcSet={image.lightboxSrcSet} src={image.lightboxSrc} alt={image.alt} />
        <div onClick={onClose} className={styles.backdrop} />
      </animated.div>
    ))
    , portalNode
  )
}
```

Comment: You will need to remove the keydown event listener, otherwise it will be kept alive causing the hook never til be GC.

Answer (score 0):

its always a good idea to any subscription; so remove keydown event listener when component unmounts;

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('keydown')
    }
  }, [])
```

and also I suspect this `onClose={() => setVisible(false)}` line; since `setState` is async and parent component might be unmounted but `onClose` callback would be run in the  portal (child) component and hence the warning.

Comment: Nope, besides this, i still get that warning. Btw the place where i put the `useEffect` is in the beneath the place where i have the React.useState. Is that the right place? Because on the place where you put it, is was unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

try to add listener when your component mounts (`componentDidMount` or `useEffect`).

The problem in your code is you add the listener inside a function, and every it is called, it **will** always start listening.

i would add to @Leonardo answers

```
useEffect(()=>{
  const handleKeydown = ()=>{
  // your implementations here
  // and yes, you define the handleKeydown here inside useEffect
  }

  window.addListener('keydown', handleKeydown)

  // this peace of code will be run when your component unmounts
  return window.removeListener('keydown');

  // this [] means it only run once on mount.
},[])
```

Comment: But what is the place i have to use the useEffect exactly?

Comment: directly in your component, not nested in any function. My personal preference is after i use `useState`s declaration